# Unable to confirm sales order in odoo

Tags: odoo-12

Here is the error shown below.

No procurement rule found in location "Partner Locations/Customers" for product "A".
Check routes configuration.

I would also like to know why are the sales orders being redirected to only one company though the product of that particular order belongs to another company. How can we redirect orders respective to the product owners?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set you rules in Inventory. Did you by any chance upgraded from a previous version of Odoo?
In Odoo 12 - Go to Inventory -> Configuration -> Routes and create routes for receiving and getting out products. Then go to Inventory -> Configuration -> Routes and adjust the routes for delivering to customers: Pull From / WH/Stock to Partner Locations/Customers.

This is how I manage to do it after upgrading from Odoo 10 to Odoo 12. I will look more in depth to see if there are also other open dependencies.